# mongodb osx (installed with brew), while db runing commands dont work

Tags: macos, mongodb

I installed mongodb on mac using brew and official guides. mongodb seemed to installed correctly. when i go to terminal and type `sudo mongod` it produces bunch of logs and final that db is listening on port `27017` i can open tab in browser `localhost:27017` which doesnt seem to do anything but at least i know it works. mongodb is taking over terminal and i can type commands but i dont get any response for any command. i tried:

- show dbs
- use testdb

and so on. doesnt matter what i type it never returns any response. what did i do wrong?

OSX 10.9.5
db version 3.2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/)  command you entered refers to the mongo daemon process which runs in the background.

Try typing mongo in your terminal instead of mongod and you should see the following input with the '>' prompt:

`MongoDB shell version x.x.x
connecting to: xxx`

Then you can type `show dbs` and see your databases.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, i didnt notice that i was trying to operate on wrong process. Thank You for pointing that out ;)